# Whenever I type pip install on my Mac I get this error: fish: 'pip install tweepy' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)

Tags: macos, pip, fish

Whenever I type `pip install` on my Mac, I get this error 
`fish: 'pip install tweepy' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)` and then I get this popup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt1VB.jpg
It does not matter what Python library I try to install, I just get the same error

Comment: Why are you running Python v2.7 anyway? It is end-of-lifed in 4 days.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Does it mean Python 2.7, pip or 3rd-party libs will stop working in 4 days?

Comment: No, it means there will br no updates or support and as Python 3 has been out for 11 years it is probably time to move on and stop worrying about Python v2 issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the fish shell. The python 2.7 binary used by pip is attempting to load the */usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib* shared library and that library in turn is calling `abort()`. Probably because it isn't compatible with the python 2.7 binary you installed with Homebrew. You probably recently updated macOS but didn't update the software installed by Homebrew. Try running `brew upgrade` then `brew update`.

And, as Mark noted in his comments, python 2.7 is dead and you really should switch to python 3.x.